# Posterior Predictive Checks in R using rjags

Tags: self-study, bayesian, predictive-models, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am working on a problem that involves the following information.
[image]

[image]

I have managed to answer the first part of the question using the following r-code that allows me to compute the posterior probabilities.

```
 library(rjags)

# Load the data
 Y      <- c(64,72,55,27,75,24,28,66,40,13)

 n      <- c(75,95,63,39,83,26,41,82,54,16)

 q      <- c(0.845,0.847,0.880,0.674,0.909,
             0.898,0.770,0.801,0.802,0.875)

 X      <- log(q/(1-q))

# Define the model: 
 nba_model <- "model{
  for(i in 1:10){
    Y[i]          ~ dbinom(pi[i],n[i])
    logit(pi[i]) <- beta1 + beta2*X[i]
  }
  beta1 ~ dnorm(0,0.1)
  beta2 = 1+delta*gamma
  gamma ~ dbern(0.5)
  delta ~ dnorm(0,prec)
 }"

# Conduct the analysis for various priors sds, c 

pri_sd <- c(0.5,1,2)
for(c in pri_sd){
 mod <- textConnection(nba_model)
 data  <- list(Y=Y,X=X,n=n,prec=1/c^2)
 model <- jags.model(mod,data = data, n.chains=2,quiet=TRUE)
 update(model, 10000, progress.bar="none")
 samps <- coda.samples(model, variable.names=c("gamma"),
                      n.iter=100000, thin=10,progress.bar="none")
 print(c)
 print(summary(samps)$statistics)
}
```

However, I am not even sure where to begin with the second part that is asking me to fit the M2 model to the data and use posterior predictive checks to verify the model fits well. Any help is appreciated.